# SelectOneMenu : NullPointerException

Tags: hibernate, spring, nullpointerexception, primefaces, selectonemenu

i'm trying to populate a primefaces's SelectOneMenu but the application hits a  NullPointerException, i don't know where is the problem.
here is my SelectOneMenu code:

```
     <h:outputText value="Domaine : " styleClass="champ"/>
       <p:selectOneMenu value="#{projet.currentProjet.typeProjets}" >  
           <f:selectItem itemLabel="Domaine" itemValue="" />  
           <f:selectItems value="#{projet.inittprojet()}"  var="typeprojet" itemValue="#{typeprojet}" itemLabel="#{typeprojet.designation}" />  
       </p:selectOneMenu>
```

here is my backing bean:

```
            @Component("projetsBean")
@Scope("session") <br>
public class ProjetsBean implements Serializable{ <br>
    private transient ProjetsService projetsService;


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// setters & getters \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

public void setProjetsService(ProjetsService projetsService)
{
    this.projetsService=projetsService;
}
public ProjetsService getProjetsService()
{
    return projetsService;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Méthodes  \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
@PostConstruct
```

public List inittprojet()
    {

```
   return projetsService.getAllProjets();
}
```

}

regards

Comment: public List<Projets>  inittprojet()
    {
        
       return projetsService.getAllProjets();
    }

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't show the stacktrace or at least the line where the NPE happens, I can only guess, but one thing seems suspicious.

You should use a non-selectable option in SelectOneMenu this way:

```
<f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true" itemLabel="Domaine"/>
```

If you omit the `noSelectionOption="true"`, a NPE can occur because jsf treats it as selectable option.

Comment: hey, the line of the error is: return projetsService.getAllProjets();

Comment: here is my faces-config :
 <managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>projet</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.mycompany.projet.ProjetsBean</managed-bean-class>
 
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
   <property-name>projetsService</property-name>
   <value>#{projetsService}</value>
                        <property-name>changerStatusService</property-name>
   <value>#{changerStatusService}</value>
  </managed-property></managed-bean>

Comment: the problem is that i tested the methode projetsService.getAllProjets() on JUnit and it's working... so i don't understand why it's not working on my backup bean

Comment: hey, i solved the problem, it was a small issue on my faces-config which is the <managed-property> so i changed it to:
<managed-property> <property-name>projetsService</property-name> <value>#{projetsService}</value> </managed-property> <managed-property> <property-name>changerStatusService</property-name> <value>#{changerStatusService}</value> </managed-property>